# How to resolve dependencies npm conflict?

Tags: javascript, npm

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "reactjs",
  "version": "4.7.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.2.2",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@craco/craco": "^5.6.2",
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "4.4.2",
    "@types/d3-scale": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/react-bootstrap-table-next": "^4.0.18",
    "abp-web-resources": "^5.1.1",
    "antd": "^4.6.4",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "craco-antd": "^1.14.1",
    "d3-scale": "^4.0.2",
    "echarts": "^5.3.2",
    "echarts-for-react": "^3.0.2",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "highcharts": "^10.2.0",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mobx": "^6.5.0",
    "mobx-react": "^7.4.0",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^3.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "query-string": "^6.9.0",
    "rc-slider": "^8.7.1",
    "rc-tooltip": "^4.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^3.3.5",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-editor": "^1.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.1.1",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.11.0",
    "react-datetime": "^2.16.3",
    "react-document-title": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-image-crop": "^9.0.3",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-notifications": "^1.4.3",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.3",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "react-select": "^5.3.2",
    "react-vis": "^1.11.7",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.5.4",
    "sweetalert2-react": "^0.8.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.dev craco start",
    "start-local": "env-cmd -f .env.local craco start",
    "start-production": "env-cmd -f .env.production craco start",
    "build": "env-cmd -f .env.dev craco build",
    "build-local": "env-cmd -f .env.local craco build",
    "build-production": "env-cmd -f .env.production craco build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.9",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.23",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.12",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.14",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.13",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^4.4.1",
    "@types/react-document-title": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "@types/react-loadable": "^5.5.2",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/react-vis": "^1.11.11",
    "@types/recharts": "^1.8.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.5",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.17.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "ts-import-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "16.3.0"
  }
}
```

What I've done:

- yarn - install correctly but finally I had:
  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyWer.png)
- npm ci
- npm i
- npm i --force and npm i --legacy-peer-deps(both install modules, but finally I had an error)
- tried to add resolutions to package.json
- deleted package-lock, yarn.lock and node_modules and after npm i or yarn
- tried different versions of react in resolution package

Node version: tried with 14.15 and then updated to 16.17
NPM: 8.11.0

with resolutions like I have in package.json:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWsoL.png)

without resolutions:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x10ZI.png)

Got a archive with all fronted files(with node modules) and tried to start(failed), but on other windows machine project started correctly(Node 14.15, npm version 6)

U.P.D new error: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmBtv.png)

U.P.D 2: maybe it makes more sense to resolve the issues from the first screen shot?

Comment: Which of the three errors are you trying to solve?

Comment: I try to figure out which the correct way to install modules and start the project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolve your dependencies you will have to change the used versions. your `package.json` requires `"react": "^18.1.0",` while `react-bootstrap-table-next` requires `"react": "^16.3.0",`.

If you want to resolve your conflict you will have to update `react-bootstrap-table-next` to a version which supports `"react": "^18.1.0",` or downgrade your react dependency in the `package.json` to `"react": "^16.3.0",`

Comment: ok, I don't know why, but I've got another error(you can see U.P.D